# How do I send JSON Data to JasperReports via POST?

Tags: java, json, jasper-reports

I would like to know how to POST JSON data to a *JasperReports* report, which would then store this data in a *java.util.Collection* and use it to populate the report.

Also, could someone comment on the *correctness* of this approach? We are planning not to use any data source whatsoever. The data for the report would be sent in POST itself.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Are you willing to do it using the JasperReports Server or only the Jasper Reports engine?

Comment: I am fine using JasperReports Server if needed.